# Why while loop is printing one line?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to print using C:

```
01010
01010
01010
01010
```

using nested loops and if only, I created this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n = 1, x = 0, count = 1, m = 0;
    while (m <= 5)
    {
        while (n <= 5)
        {
            if (x == 0)
            {
                printf("%d", x);
                x++;
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                printf("%d", x);
                x--;
            }
            n++;
        }
        m++;
    }
}
```

But the output is `01010` one line only, may I know what's the reason and how should I fix it?

Comment: Generally you should fix it by running your program in a debugger. Step through it and check variables. Especially your loop variable `n` might show an interesting value which prevents your inner loop to be entered after the first line.

Comment: Formatting your `{ }` properly might help in seeing the problem.

Comment: Also: `main` function is supposed to have return type `int`.

Comment: You need to reset `x` within the outer loop. That is, right after `while (n <= 5) {` you should have `x = 0;`, for example.

Comment: `n` still is 5 when the second outer loop starts, so no inner loop will be performed.

Comment: There is no `\n` in any of the `printf`s, so the output of the program will always be 1 line only.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the tips and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0, x = 0; j < 5; ++j, x=!x)
            printf("%d", x);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Your problem is that the `while` loop does not reset `n` and `x`. A `for` loop is better, it always starts with the initialization part before the first iteration. To fix your code add `x=0; n=1;` before `while (n <= 5)`.

You also did not print a newline, so everything would be in the same line.

Your `if (x==0) x++; else if (x==1) x--;` is the same as `x = !x;`, from `0` to `1` and from `1` to `0`.